# Как пользоваться схемой примеров SCOTT в версии 19c?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

Хочу попробовать примеры из схемы `SCOTT`. Пытаюсь подсоединиться:

```sql
$ sqlplus -l scott/tiger@dbsrv/pdb1
```

> ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Разблокировка тоже заканчивается ошибкой:

```sql
SQL> alter user scott account unlock identified by tiger;
```

> ORA-01918: user 'SCOTT' does not exist

<sub>Свободный перевод [Unlocking SCOTT user in oracle 19c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61191438/6571020) от участника [@misaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13303104/misaki)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/61191438/6571020

Answer (score 2):

Как замечено в документации [гл. Introduction to Sample Schemas](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/comsc/introduction-to-sample-schemas.html#GUID-844E92D8-A4C8-4522-8AF5-761D4BE99200):

> For many years, Oracle used the simple database schema `SCOTT`, with its two prominent tables `EMP` and `DEPT`, for various examples in documentation and training. **These tables are inadequate to show the basic features** of Oracle Database and other Oracle products.

Начиная с выпуска 12.2 схема `SCOTT` больше не входит в комплект поставляемых схем примеров. Вместо неё надо использовать схему `HR` или создать её скриптами из более старых выпусков (взять можно [например тут](https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/blob/master/schemas/scott.sql)).

---

Установка детально описана в [гл. Installing Sample Schemas](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/comsc/installing-sample-schemas.html#GUID-1E645D09-F91F-4BA6-A286-57C5EC66321D). Но возьмите на заметку:

> During a complete installation of Oracle Database, the HR schema can be installed either manually or automatically when creating a database using the dbca option. All the other sample schemas must be installed manually via the scripts available on GitHub.

Во время полной установки БД только схема `HR` может быть создана автоматически, если указано при создания БД с `dbca -sampleSchema true`, или вручную позже. Все остальные схемы примеров могут быть установленны только вручную и доступны для загрузки на [GitHub](https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas/releases).

После установки схем примеров, соответствующий пользователь должен быть разблокирован, например:

```
alter user hr account unlock identified by hr;
```