# Почему не устанавливается БД через установщик setup?

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

В чем может быть проблема при установке Oracle Database 19c ([ссылка где скачивал](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/oracle-database-software-downloads.html#19c)).

- Распаковываю архив и нажимаю на setup.
- После этого дальше пустого окна установки дело не доходит.
- Установку я прерываю закрывая окно установщика.

Comment: Вы всё выполняете по [инструкции](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ntdbi/index.html)?

Comment: Проблема может заключаться в пути до установочного файла. Попробуй извлечь в корень установщик, чтобы небыло пробелов и на всякий случай кириллицы

Answer (score 4):

> Распаковываю архив и нажимаю на setup

**Следует учесть**: БД это довольно сложный программный продукт, его установка требует базовых знаний в облати ОС и БД. Их будет явно недостаточно, если их хватает только на действие - *нажать на setup*.

Рекомендуется воспользоваться [оф. инструкцией по устанновке](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ntdbi/index.html) (как минимим прочитать "по диагонали"). Предложеная ниже инструкция, попытка провести установку оставляя все, что только возможно, значениями по-умолчанию, чтобы избежать необходимости расширенных познаний в архитектуре и конфигурации БД.

---

Установка БД 19c на Windows 10 Home десктоп или ноутбук в учебных или тестовых целях.

1. Скачайте с [оф. сайта архив последней версии для Windows платформы](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/oracle-database-software-downloads.html).
2. Создайте директорию, куда будет установлена БД. Использовать кириллические симоволы и пробелы **не рекомендуется**. Создайте, например: `D:\app\oracle\orcl`. Разархивируйте туда скаченый ранее архив. В данном случае, позднее понадобятся переменные окружения:

   ```
   ORACLE_BASE=D:\app\oracle
   ORACLE_HOME=D:\app\oracle\orcl
   ```
3. Откройте CMD **как администратор** и перейдите во вновь созданную директорию. Теперь запустите установщик:

   ```
   D:\app\oracle\orcl19c> setup.exe
   Launching Oracle Database Setup Wizard...
   ```
4. В появившемся окне установщика нажимая <kbd>Next</kbd> следуйте до *Steep 4 of 8*, оставляя всё как есть. Здесь задайте (или оставте предложенное по-умолчанию):

   - Global datebase name: **orcl**
   - Password: *******
   - Pluggable datebase name: **pdb1**

   Обязательно запомните эти данные. Переменная окружения для SID (системного идентификатора образа БД) и строка соединения будут такими:

   ```
   ORACLE_SID=orcl
   cnnect_string=user/password@<db host IP or URL>:1521/pdb1
   ```
5. Следуйте далее до *Steep 6 of 8* и нажмите <kbd>Install</kbd>
6. Дождитесь окончания установки (*Steep 8 of 8*) и нажмите <kbd>Close</kbd>.
   В окне CMD найдите сообщение:

   ```
   You can find the log of this install session at:
    C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory\logs\InstallActions2020-10-08_04-22-19PM\installActions2020-10-08_04-22-19PM.log
   ```

   Это лог установки и к нему следует обращаться в случае ошибок.
7. Закройте окнo CMD и откройте его теперь с обычным пользователем. Выполните подключение как привилигированый БД пользователь `SYS`:

   ```
   C:\> set ORACLE_HOME=D:\app\oracle\orcl
   C:\> sqlplus / as sysdba 

   Connected to:
   Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
   Version 19.3.0.0.0

   SQL> show pdbs

        CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
    ---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
             2 PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY  NO
             3 PDB1                           READ WRITE NO
   ```

   Текущее местоположение - контейнер БД (CDB), здесь ничего создавать и менять не надо. В контейнере запущены: шаблон для новых БД (`PDB$SEED`) и только что созданая пустая БД (`PDB1`), в которую и следует перейти:

   ```
   SQL> alter session set container=pdb1
   /
   Session altered.

   SQL> show con_name

    CON_NAME
    ------------------------------
    PDB1
   ```

Всё в порядке. В новой пустой БД создайте нового пользователя и работайте **только** с ним (не с `SYS`).

---

На этом ресурсе уже есть следующие темы, которых помогут осуществить дальнейшие шаги:

[Как создать пользователя БД с минимумом прав и привилегий?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/830898)

[Создание БД в Oracle без системных таблиц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1152548)

[Не могу подключиться к БД через SQL*Plus после создания нового пользователя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1150768)

[Как пользоваться схемой примеров SCOTT в версии 19c?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1110296)

Comment: огогогогогогого!

Comment: @nörbörnën Это было восхищение или недоумение?

Comment: я фанат ваших ответов

Comment: Спасибо! Когда я песни пел, фанатов у меня не было, ну хоть теперь :)