# При установке Oracle Database ошибка "Failed to add ADMIN/Admin install user to %2% group"

Tags: oracle, windows-10

Не получается установить Oracle Database. В финале вылезает ошибка:

Failed to add ADMIN/Admin install user to %2% group

При инсталляции указывал и простого юзера и админа, добалял группу "%2%"- не помогло. Windows 10 LTSC.
Подскажите пожалуйста, чего оно от меня хочет?

Comment: попробуй от админа запустить или войти в систему тоже через админа

Comment: в интернетах пишут, что имя компа и имя пользователя еще нужны разные, тогда работает

Comment: handowl, смена имени сработала, процесс установки явно прошёл дальше чем раньше, но потом прилетело вот это: 
"[INS-20802] Oracle Net Configuration Assistant failed."
В любом случае большое спасибо.

Comment: Как-то делал упрощённую [инструкцию по установке на Windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1179831/217579). Посмотрите, поможет ли?